# Get field names returned from any sql statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I want to get a list of the field names returned from a sql statement.  This can be done using a sql statement or some c# parsing code to parse the statement as a string.  Can this be done easily without writing a complex parser?

For example I may want to return

name, field2, field3

from

```
SELECT a.field1 as name, a.field2, b.field3 FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.Id = B.FkId
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are asking about using SqlClient components, such as the [SqlDataReader Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx), you can use the

```
Reader.GetName(columnNumber)
```

Method to return the column name.

Comment: This sounds like the sort of thing I'm after.  The only downside is it will require a db hit which I guess will be requited.  I can just alter the statemt to just return a single method then use the reader to get the name

Comment: @Sheff "it will require a db hit": Yes it will. The alternative of writing a SQL parser needs to consider aggregate expressions, sub-queries, ... and is therefore not easy.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `DataSet` or `DataTable`, you can access its `Columns` property, which is a collection of `DataColumn` objects. The column name can then be accessed like so:

```
// assume dt is DataTable
string colname = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a SqlDataReader, which most people are, you can retrieve the field names using the following code

```
Private Shared Function GetDataRecordColumns(ByVal dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader) As List(Of String)

    '' list to contain the columns
    Dim ls As New List(Of String)

    For x As Integer = 0 To dr.FieldCount - 1
        ls.Add(dr.GetName(x))
    Next

    Return ls

End Function
```

In case you are using a dataset or datatable, the following function can be used (Simply pass in your dataset.Table(0) if you are working with a dataset)

```
Private Shared Function GetDataRecordcolumns(ByVal dt As DataTable) As List(Of String)

        Dim ls As New List(Of String)

        For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            ls.Add(col.ColumnName)
        Next

        Return ls

 End Function
```

Hope this helps

G

Comment: This is vb - the OP specified C#